# Issue with Siri suddenly misunderstanding what I say

Tags: iphone, siri, voice-dictation

Siri used to be great for voice dictation on my iPhone. All worked well. One day, though, she started misunderstanding one specific sentence, namely "à la ligne" (new paragraph, in French). since then, she transcribes by writing "/" instead of actually starting a new paragraph.

I tried resetting her database (turning here on and off in setting, as well as "voice dictation"), but nothing works.

I'm using the latest iOS 9.01 on a non-jailbroken iPhone 6.

Any idea what's wrong, and how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting her database again, but then force restart (hold lock button and home button together until an Apple logo appears) afterwards.

Comment: This didn't do it either, it's very strange...

Comment: @Rodolphe What version if iOS are you running? Also, is your iPhone jailbroken?

Comment: iOS 9, not jailbroken

Comment: @Rodolphe 9.0? Or 9.0.1?

Comment: 9.01 actually :)

Comment: @Rodolphe That's really weird. I'd give Apple support a call.